# Get device screen diagonal size in inches

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have Xamarin PCL project and I have this code to calculate device screen diagonal size in inches (for Android):

```cs
public class DeviceInfoService_Droid : IDeviceInfoService
{
    public DeviceInfoModel GetDeviceInfo()
    {
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        IWindowManager windowManager = 
          Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(
            Android.Content.Context.WindowService).JavaCast<IWindowManager>();
        windowManager.DefaultDisplay.GetMetrics(dm);
        int w = dm.WidthPixels;
        int h = dm.HeightPixels;
        double wi = (double)width / (double)dm.Xdpi;
        double hi = (double)height / (double)dm.Ydpi;
        double x = Math.Pow(wi, 2);
        double y = Math.Pow(hi, 2);
        double screenInches = Math.Sqrt(x + y);

        ...
    }
}
```

But for my 5" phone it gives result screenInches = 2.4173. What am I doing wrong? Another solution for getting screen size would also be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your error could be here:

```
int w = dm.WidthPixels;
int h = dm.HeightPixels;
double wi = (double)width / (double)dm.Xdpi;
double hi = (double)height / (double)dm.Ydpi;
```

You are using `width` and `height` instead of `WidthPixels` and `HeightPixels`

I think you want:

```
int w = dm.WidthPixels;
int h = dm.HeightPixels;
double wi = (double)w / (double)dm.Xdpi;
double hi = (double)h / (double)dm.Ydpi;
```

Comment: You are right. Width and height are WidthPixels / 2 and HeightPixels / 2. So I get screenInches = 2.4173 * 2 which is still not 5''

Comment: @Uros Not true. You actually have `sqrt([WidthPixels/2]^2 + [HeightPixels/2]^2)`. I would try my solution and let me know if you get `2.4173 * 2 = 4.8` Because I dont think you will. I think you'll get 5

Comment: Here is how I get 4.8: sqrt([dm.WidthPixels / dm.Xdpi] ^ 2 + [dm.HeightPixels / dm.Ydpi] ^ 2) = sqrt([720 / 294.967] ^ 2 + [1280 / 306.716] ^ 2) = sqrt([2.441] ^ 2 + [4.173] ^2) = 4.8346

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are doing way too many conversions.

I would rather use:

```
public class DeviceInfoService_Droid : IDeviceInfoService
{
    public DeviceInfoModel GetDeviceInfo()
    {
        var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        var widthInDp = (int)((metrics.WidthPixels) / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
        var heightInDp = (int)((metrics.HeightPixels) / Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density);
        double x = Math.Pow(widthInDp , 2);
        double y = Math.Pow(heightInDp , 2);
        double screenInches = Math.Sqrt(x + y);
        .....
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2:**
Actually this gives you the Device Independant Pixels size. To get that in inches (depending on the device DPI):

```
public class DeviceInfoService_Droid : IDeviceInfoService
{
    public DeviceInfoModel GetDeviceInfo()
    {
        var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
        var widthInPx = metrics.WidthPixels;
        var heightInPx = metrics.HeightPixels;
        var heightInInches = heightInPx/metrics.ydpi;
        var widthInInches = widthInPx/metrics.xdpi;
        double x = Math.Pow(widthInInches, 2);
        double y = Math.Pow(heightInInches, 2);
        double screenInches = Math.Sqrt(x + y);
        .....
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: On line
var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
there is an error:
An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Resources.DisplayMetrics'

Comment: Instead of Resources.DisplayMetrics, I can use Android.App.Application.Context.Resources.DisplayMetrics and then it compiles, but gives wrong result: WidthPixels = 720, HeightPixels = 1280, Density = 2, screenInches = 734.302

Comment: If I put using Android.App.Application.Context; there is an error The type name 'Context' does not exist in the type 'Application'. My device dimensions are 360x640. Xdpi = 294.967, Ydpi = 306.716, DensityDpi = 320. It is a 5'' Samsung phone.

Comment: Edited answer gives 2.467 instead of 5''. Here is how: widthInDp = 720 / 2 = 360, heightInDp = 1280 / 2 = 640, heightInInches = 640 / 294.967, widthInInches = 360 / 306.716, screenInches = 2.467

Comment: Right. In this case, we don't want to divide the pixels by the  `Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density`, my mistake (edited again). So we just convert from the pixels to inches according to the device dpi. Though with your given device info, the result is 4.9333...

Comment: I agree, but that seems like not-good-enough answer... I would like to get 5''

Comment: Actually, sorry to disappoint you, but this is how you get your diagonal size in inch. So maybe make sure it's really 5'' first.

Comment: Las but not least, Are you running on an emulator? If so, please test this code on a real device! Because issues were reported on Android software Emulators returning an incorrect density. So, please test on actual hardware.

Comment: I found my phone model (Samsung Galaxy J500H) on internet and screen is 5''. I also took actual meter to check if it is really 5'' and the value is correct.